# Обфусация кода, Защита от декомпиляции

Tags: c#, обфускация

Собственно, кто какие способы защиты от декомпиляции программы и кто какие способы обфуксации кода написанного на c# знает?

Comment: интересно, а зачем?

Comment: есть такая программа, называется С++:)

Comment: @dreamchild Мне мои "программки" смысла ообфуцировать и защищать, нет. Просто интересна информация и методы.
@KoVadim Для C++ я слишком труслив и никчёмен.

Comment: Невозможно защитить программу написанную на .net, на все известные обфускаторы есть рефлеторы c плагинами, которые прекрасно деобфусцируют код. Единственный вариант защититься, выполнять всю логику в облаке и отправлять пользователю результат.

Comment: Может вас интересует что-то конкретное? А то обзорных материалов в сети достаточно:

 1. http://habrahabr.ru/post/97062/
 2. http://hashcode.ru/questions/188620

Comment: @beliy26rus На хабре читал статью (обзор обфуксаторов), пишут, что .NET Reactor хорошая штуковина. И код не деобфуцируется.

@Jofsey Я искать в сети умею. Первую статью видел и читал.

Comment: А Вам для диссертации или для практического применения?

Comment: @Чад В начале я получу докторскую за диссертацию, а потом буду практически применять  для своих "гениальных проектов".
Вообще я хотел просто узнать способы, которые люди использовали для защиты своих программ.

Но я вижу, что здесь только издеваются, так что, закройте кто-нибудь тему.

Comment: Если серьёзно: большая часть программы не является секретом. Это обычно UI (который не скопируешь), бизнес-логика (которая специфична для каждого приложения, и поэтому никому чужому не интересна), обвязки моделей и тому подобный boilerplate. Защищать имеет смысл лишь алгоритмическую часть. А вот с этим можно и поработать. Но проще всего выгрузить её на сервер, тогда-то уж её точно никто не взломает.

Comment: Подойдём с другой стороны: вы когда-нибудь пробовали разобраться в чужом сложном коде, написанном без комментариев и с нечитаемыми именами переменных? Это дико сложно, не говоря уж о поддержке такого кода (поищите по форуму, такие проблемы регулярно встречаются). А при декомпиляции вы получаете вариант не лучше: там такая вся программа.

Украсть код, даже исходники, не даст ничего. Уводить надо команду разработчиков, кого-нибудь, кто _понимает_ логику кода и знает, как с ней работать.

Так что не парьтесь. Никому исходники не нужны.

Comment: Да, я не парюсь, походу меня тут никто не понял. Я просто хотел узнать МЕТОДЫ обфуксации и защиты от декомпиляции.

Comment: @MadKeks: Да метод-то простой: (1) берёте один из существующих обфускаторов, (2) прогоняете через него, (3) профит.

Правда, в последнее время появилась и другая альтернатива: [Project N](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Если вам правда нужна такая защита, то попробуйте вот что:
Все названия переменных пишите задом наперёд:

    mSomeString -> gnirtSemoSm

Строки конвертируйте в base64.

В каждый метод пихайте аргумент, который не должен использоваться:

    void doiVemoS(String ataDdesU, int hrenZnaetZachemEto)

И в середине метода, например, сделайте проверку:

    if (hrenZnaetZachemEto == 7) log("0JLRiyDRgtGA0LDRgtC40YLQtSDQstGA0LXQvNGPINC30YDRjw==");
    
От такого кода у "хакера" на первых 50 строках отпадёт желание не только продолжать в этом разбираться, но и пользоваться вашей программой вообще.

Comment: От профи конечно ничего не спасет, но эта комплексная защита у многих отобьет охоту ковыряться в твоем приложении - [Enigma Protector](http://enigmaprotector.com/ru). Да и цена приемлемая.

Comment: Еще один способ защиты msil кода это его трансформация в пикод виртуальной машины с последующем полным удалением оригинального тела метода.
Так поступает ILvirt : https://ilvirt.pro

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Но я вижу, что здесь только издеваются, так что, закройте кто-нибудь тему

[[@MadKeks](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks) никто над вами не издевается, не преувеличивайте. 
Дело в том, что необходимость в обфускации программ на C# сама по себе довольно сомнительна - очень существенная часть C# кода - это веб-приложения, веб-сервисы и прочий код, который работает на сервере, а следовательно,  конечный пользователь его не видит и покопаться в нем не сможет даже с помощью ildasm'a или Reflector'a. Большая часть оставшегося софта - это программы, используемые очень ограниченным кругом лиц (внутрикорпоративные  десктоп-приложения например), а следовательно, никому не придет в голову воровать их исходный код, не представляющий особой ценности. 
К примеру, на своей первой работе я получил в сопровождение кучу адского говнокода, нарушающего все возможные и невозможные каноны чистоты кода и в каккой-то степени благодаря этому уже являвшийся обфусцированным (справедливости ради, мои навыки на тот момент как раз того и стоили - из под моих пальцев вытекал точно такой же кривой говнокод). Так вот что тогда, что сейчас я бы не только не стал этот код воровать с помощью декомпиляции, я бы не стал брать его даже даром из исходников.

В подобной защите, вероятно, нуждается серьезное проприетарное ПО, скажем, какой-нибудь Photoshop, но оно на C# обычно не пишется.

Учитывая, что исходники практически на все случаи жизни можно отыскать на всяческих гитхабах и битбакетах, пляски с бубном для получения исходников становятся еще более сомнительными.

Стоит также отметить вот что: на моей памяти 99% процентов случаев, когда программист волновался по этому поводу сводились к тому, что это был юный и неопытный разработчик, искренне  уверенный в том, что его хелловорлды способны потрясти мир и произвести революцию в области софта, а потому срочно нуждаются в защите и сокрытии своих исходников. По мере профессионального взросления у них это обычно проходило.

Впрочем, при желании материалов на эту тему  можно найти достаточно. Например [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74204/) и [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/97062/)

**UPD**

[статья по обфускации в .NET](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74463/)

[обфускация в JS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112530/)

Стоит кстати заметить, что обфускация во многом зависит от средств конкретного языка

Comment: @VladD Да надоели уже, одному интересно, какой супер софт я буду защищать, второй спрашивает для чего мне это. 
А я просто хотел услышать нормальный ответ, вида:
1) Rename переменных до уродского вида
2) Склейка с супер-технонанопрограмками, которые Reflector открыть не может
3)...

Comment: @MadKeks пожалуйста, не надо истерик. Если вы обратите внимание, никто над вами тут не издевается и не прикалывается, вам вполне адекватно и аргументированно пишут по вышеозначенной теме. Задаваемые вам наводящие вопросы нужны лишь для уточнения деталей вопроса. Агрессию и издевки над вами видите только вы. Пожалуйста, держите себя более адекватно

Comment: @MadKeks я не могу отвечать за других людей, но на мой взгляд это максимум легкая ирония, не более

Comment: @DreamChild  Что для вас лёгкая ирония, для меня - издёвка.

Comment: @MadKeks это дело ваше, конечно, на что обижаться, но все же принимать за оскорбление/издевку подобные слова - это никаких нервов не хватит, имхо. 

Да, если все же речь зашла о методах обфускации, то я дополнил ответ, возможно, будет полезно

Comment: @DreamChild *"В подобной защите, вероятно, нуждается серьезное проприетарное ПО, скажем, какой-нибудь Photoshop, но оно на C# обычно не пишется."* Категорически не согласен с тем, что серьёзные программы на C# не пишутся. И в целом с посылом статьи, что необходимость в обфускации сомнительна. Напротив, если она сделана грамотно, то она способна сильно усложнить жизнь взломщика.

Comment: @DreamChild В целом автор вообще не спрашивал про "Стоит ли обфусцировать или нет", а спрашивал про способы, а вы почему-то решили отговаривать людей от обфускации. Про методы, кроме ссылок, у вас в ответе ни слова. Поэтому считаю сам ответ бесполезным из-за сведений никак не относящихся к вопросу. "Говнокод", опенсорс, программы неопытных программистов — вообще оффтопик.

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение к ответу [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) (с которым на 100% согласен), а также в рамках популяризации новых веяний в разработке на .NET, упомяну ещё одну альтернативу.

С выходом [Developer Preview Project N](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), вы можете скомпилировать ваше .NET-приложение в нативный код, и даже прилинковать к нему всю стандартную библиотеку (ну да, выйдет файл размером в типичное C++-приложение). Так что вскрыть его будет не легче, чем C++-программу (и даже труднее, т. к. спецы во взломе C++-кода должны ещё привыкнуть к коду, генерируемому AOT-компилятором .NET, и его системным библиотекам).

Ещё раз повторюсь, что это занятие (обфускация) по моему мнению пустая трата времени.

Comment: @DreamChild Собственно про c# на хабре я уже прочитал. А вот JS интересно.. Но увы, ни http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum_com.php , ни http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html  не захотели у меня работать =(

Comment: тут еще стоит отметить, что в случае с JS просто сжать код в одну стрчку не очень надежно - отформатировать его несложно, а изворачиваться в стиле Brainfuck может быть опасно - нет стопроцентной гарантии, что код будет иметь ту же функциональность, что и до обфускации, и уж тем более нет гарантии, что он не просядет в производительности

Comment: @DreamChild Ну, я под тот же js хорошего и достойного не самописного обфуксатора,  не видел.

Comment: @MadKeks учитывая открытость js-скриптов, его необходимость еще менее оправдана

Comment: @DreamChild  Почему же ?

Comment: @MadKeks скрывать то, что и без того открыто  чаще всего не стоит затрат. Обычно достаточно бывает лишь сжать скрипт, тем более, что обычно это делается для минимизации трафика, а не для запутывания. Более того, основная логика в веб-приложениях гнездится на сервере, а не на клиенте