# Как сделать код C# недекомпилируемым?

Tags: c#

Есть файл с кодом. Каким образом возможно зашифровать его (или сделать его зашифрованным при декомпиляции)?

Comment: Если кратко, то никак.

Comment: Переписать на С++

Comment: @user7860670 а что мне дальше делать с этим?

Comment: Скомпилировать. Декомпилировать не получится.

Comment: @aepot а если не кратко. Может существуют какие-нибудь способы, хотя бы в идее дающие такой результат?

Comment: @weeqn Обычно чем более высокоуровневый язык, тем сложнее такое сделать.

Comment: @weeqn https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/?view=vs-2022

Comment: Уже обсуждалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/337719/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Чисто в теории можно писать на F# и получишь код который хоть и декомпилируется в C# но будет совсем нечитабельной белибердой))) Как второй вариант (не проверял) - в теории если писать функциональный код на шарпе то декомпилированный код так же будет выглядеть очень плохочитабельным. Но в целом если не хочешь что бы код декомпилировали - пиши  код на С++ или ассемблере)))